# dataframe columns as key and column data as value group by id in spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in spark. I want to get all the column names into one column(as key) and and all values into column (as value) group by id.

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("101"," FIXED"," 2000-01-01"," null"," null"," .0125484200"),("102"," VARRY"," 2018-09-14"," 4.3980"," 0.0"," .3518450000"), ("103"," FIXED"," 2001-02-01"," null"," null"," .0000023564"), ("103"," FIXED"," 2011-02-23"," 4.83"," 2414.6887"," .0020154800"), ("104"," FIXED"," 2000-01-01"," null"," null"," .0215487400"))).toDF("Id","type","datecol","value1"," value2","finalvalue")

df.show

+---+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+
| Id|  type|    datecol| value1|    value2|  finalvalue|
+---+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+
|101| FIXED| 2000-01-01|   null|      null| .0125484200|
|102| VARRY| 2018-09-14| 4.3980|       0.0| .3518450000|
|103| FIXED| 2001-02-01|   null|      null| .0000023564|
|103| FIXED| 2011-02-23|   4.83| 2414.6887| .0020154800|
|104| FIXED| 2000-01-01|   null|      null| .0215487400|
+---+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+
```

I need to convert the dataframe as below

```
+---+-----------+------------+
| Id|       key |     value  |
+---+-----------+------------+
|101| type      |       FIXED|
|101| datecol   |  2000-01-01|
|101| value1    |        null|
|101| value2    |        null|
|101| finalvalue| .0125484200|
|102| type      |       VARRY|
|102| datecol   |  2000-09-14|
|102| value1    |      4.3980|
|102| value2    |         0.0|
|102| finalvalue| .3518450000|
|103| type      |       FIXED|
|103| datecol   |  2000-02-01|
|103| value1    |        null|
|103| value2    |        null|
|103| finalvalue| .0000023564|
|103| type      |       FIXED|
|103| datecol   |  2000-02-23|
|103| value1    |        4.83|
|103| value2    |   2414.6887|
|103| finalvalue| .0020154800|
|104| type      |       FIXED|
|104| datecol   |  2000-01-01|
|104| value1    |        null|
|104| value2    |        null|
|104| finalvalue| .0215487400|
+---+-----------+------------+
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using stack function.

Please see code snippet with output

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("101"," FIXED"," 2000-01-01"," null"," null"," .0125484200"),("102"," VARRY"," 2018-09-14"," 4.3980"," 0.0"," .3518450000"), ("103"," FIXED"," 2001-02-01"," null"," null"," .0000023564"), ("103"," FIXED"," 2011-02-23"," 4.83"," 2414.6887"," .0020154800"), ("104"," FIXED"," 2000-01-01"," null"," null"," .0215487400"))).toDF("Id","type","datecol","value1","value2","finalvalue")
df.show()
val unPivotDF = df.select($"Id",
expr("stack(5, 'type', type, 'datecol', datecol, 'value1', value1,'value2',value2,'finalvalue',finalvalue) as (Key,Value)"))
unPivotDF.show()
```

Output :
scala> df.show()

```
+---+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+
| Id|  type|    datecol| value1|    value2|  finalvalue|
+---+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+
|101| FIXED| 2000-01-01|   null|      null| .0125484200|
|102| VARRY| 2018-09-14| 4.3980|       0.0| .3518450000|
|103| FIXED| 2001-02-01|   null|      null| .0000023564|
|103| FIXED| 2011-02-23|   4.83| 2414.6887| .0020154800|
|104| FIXED| 2000-01-01|   null|      null| .0215487400|
+---+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+
```

scala> unPivotDF.show()

```
+---+----------+------------+
| Id|       Key|       Value|
+---+----------+------------+
|101|      type|       FIXED|
|101|   datecol|  2000-01-01|
|101|    value1|        null|
|101|    value2|        null|
|101|finalvalue| .0125484200|
|102|      type|       VARRY|
|102|   datecol|  2018-09-14|
|102|    value1|      4.3980|
|102|    value2|         0.0|
|102|finalvalue| .3518450000|
|103|      type|       FIXED|
|103|   datecol|  2001-02-01|
|103|    value1|        null|
|103|    value2|        null|
|103|finalvalue| .0000023564|
|103|      type|       FIXED|
|103|   datecol|  2011-02-23|
|103|    value1|        4.83|
|103|    value2|   2414.6887|
|103|finalvalue| .0020154800|
+---+----------+------------+
```

only showing top 20 rows

==== updated part with forming columns dynamically

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("101"," FIXED"," 2000-01-01"," null"," null"," .0125484200"),("102"," VARRY"," 2018-09-14"," 4.3980"," 0.0"," .3518450000"), ("103"," FIXED"," 2001-02-01"," null"," null"," .0000023564"), ("103"," FIXED"," 2011-02-23"," 4.83"," 2414.6887"," .0020154800"), ("104"," FIXED"," 2000-01-01"," null"," null"," .0215487400"))).toDF("Id","type","datecol","value1","value2","finalvalue")
df.show()

val skipColumn = "Id"
var columnCount = df.schema.size -1
df.columns
var columnsStr = ""
var counter = 0
for ( col <- df.columns ) {
    counter = counter + 1
    if(col != skipColumn) {
        if(counter == df.schema.size) {
        columnsStr = columnsStr + s"'$col', $col"    
    }
    else {
        columnsStr = columnsStr + s"'$col', $col,"
    }
    }
}
val unPivotDF = df.select($"Id",
expr(s"stack($columnCount, $columnsStr) as (Key,Value)"))
unPivotDF.show()

scala> unPivotDF.show()
+---+----------+------------+
| Id|       Key|       Value|
+---+----------+------------+
|101|      type|       FIXED|
|101|   datecol|  2000-01-01|
|101|    value1|        null|
|101|    value2|        null|
|101|finalvalue| .0125484200|
|102|      type|       VARRY|
|102|   datecol|  2018-09-14|
|102|    value1|      4.3980|
|102|    value2|         0.0|
|102|finalvalue| .3518450000|
|103|      type|       FIXED|
|103|   datecol|  2001-02-01|
|103|    value1|        null|
|103|    value2|        null|
|103|finalvalue| .0000023564|
|103|      type|       FIXED|
|103|   datecol|  2011-02-23|
|103|    value1|        4.83|
|103|    value2|   2414.6887|
|103|finalvalue| .0020154800|
+---+----------+------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: can we get columns names dynmically at `expr("stack(5, 'type', type, 'datecol', datecol, 'value1', value1,'value2',value2,'finalvalue',finalvalue)`

Comment: It is String that you can form from columns. I have updated answer with example even though it is very basic way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that all of your columns are strings, you can use something like this. Otherwise, you will have to think of another solution because your `value` column cannot contain mixed types. You can add a filter to exclude rows where `key == "Id"`if you do not want them in your result dataframe.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def toKeyValuePairs(df: DataFrame, keyColumn: String): DataFrame = {
  import spark.implicits._
  val n = df.schema.length
  val fieldNames = df.schema.fieldNames
  df.rdd.flatMap {
    row =>
      (0 until n).map { i => (row.getAs[String](keyColumn), fieldNames(i), row.getAs[String](i)) }
  }.toDF(keyColumn, "key", "value")
}
```

```
toKeyValuePairs(df, "Id").show(10)

+---+----------+------------+
| Id|       key|       value|
+---+----------+------------+
|101|        Id|         101|
|101|      type|       FIXED|
|101|   datecol|  2000-01-01|
|101|    value1|        null|
|101|    value2|        null|
|101|finalvalue| .0125484200|
|102|        Id|         102|
|102|      type|       VARRY|
|102|   datecol|  2018-09-14|
|102|    value1|      4.3980|
+---+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try **map_from_arrays** and then **explode**

```
val df2 = df.select(array('*).as("v"), lit(df.columns).as("k"))
    .select('v.getItem(0).as("id"), map_from_arrays('k,'v).as("map"))
    .select('id, explode('map))
```

result:

```
df2.show(10)

+---+----------+------------+
| id|       key|       value|
+---+----------+------------+
|101|        Id|         101|
|101|      type|       FIXED|
|101|   datecol|  2000-01-01|
|101|    value1|        null|
|101|    value2|        null|
|101|finalvalue| .0125484200|
|102|        Id|         102|
|102|      type|       VARRY|
|102|   datecol|  2018-09-14|
|102|    value1|      4.3980|
+---+----------+------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```